How do I override the "readonly" mode on the database for a GET request for RubyOnRails 7 app?
Context
I understand that writing to the database under a GET request is against RESTful design but I am trying to install RailsMiniProfiler to my Rails '7.0.3.1' project that also uses a MySQL database. RailsMiniProfile is a simple and useful for development and I got it up and running it works as expected on every request except for the GET ones, the reason is that the GEM is trying to save the profile info into a database table and Rails somewhere is not allowing that to happen under a GET request
I get the following error message:
E, [2024-05-29T14:32:10.392477 #58380] ERROR -- : [RailsMiniProfiler] Could not save profile: Write query attempted while in readonly mode: INSERT INTO `rmp_profiled_request` 

Question(s)

Is there any way I can grant always write access to my table  rmp_profiled_request?
Where is the logic for the "readonly" mode so I can overwrite it?
Is there an special configuration value I can pass to my database.yml file?

I only intent to use RailsMiniProfiler under development so whatever tweaks I'll do it safely encapsulated only for the development environment
So far I read the docs and could not found a helpful information for this
Technical Details

Rails version:  Rails 7.0.3.1
Ruby version: ruby 3.1.4p223 (2023-03-30 revision 957bb7cb81) [x86_64-linux]
Database:  MySQL. 5.7 with mysql2 adapter (activerecord-pedantmysql2-adapter)

config/database.yml
defaults: &defaults
  adapter:         pedant_mysql2
  username:        <%= ENV['MY_API_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password:        <%= ENV['MY_API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  encoding:        utf8
  collation:       utf8_unicode_ci
  pool:            <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] %>
  timeout:         5000
  automatic_close: false

deployment_defaults: &deployment_defaults
  sslca:                 "/etc/ssl/certs/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem"
  init_command:          "SET optimizer_switch='hash_join=off'"
  variables:
   group_concat_max_len: 15000

primary_defaults: &primary_defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: <%= ENV['MY_API_DATABASE_NAME'] %>

primary_replica_defaults: &primary_replica_defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: <%= ENV['MY_API_DATABASE_NAME'] %>
    replica:  true

dw_defaults: &dw_defaults
    host:             <%= ENV['MY_DW_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database:         <%= ENV['MY_DW_DATABASE_NAME'] %>
    migrations_paths: db/migrate-dw

dw_replica_defaults: &dw_replica_defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_DW_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: <%= ENV['MY_DW_DATABASE_NAME'] %>
    replica:  true

development:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

test:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-api-test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-api-test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
    replica: true
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    host:             <%= ENV['MY_DW_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database:         my-dw-test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
    migrations_paths: db/dw_migrate
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_DW_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-dw-test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
    replica:  true

qa:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

staging:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

integration:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

production:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *deployment_defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

ci:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *primary_defaults
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *primary_replica_defaults
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *dw_defaults
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    <<: *dw_replica_defaults

demo:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
    adapter:  mysql2
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-api-demo
  primary_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    adapter:  mysql2
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_API_PRIMARY_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-api-demo
    replica:  true
  dw:
    <<: *defaults
    adapter:          mysql2
    host:             <%= ENV['MY_DW_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database:         my-dw-demo
    migrations_paths: db/migrate-dw
  dw_replica:
    <<: *defaults
    adapter:  mysql2
    host:     <%= ENV['MY_DW_REPLICA_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
    database: my-dw-demo
    replica:  true



There is no native rails prohibition about writing to a database from a get method. Do you have multiple databases set up and have your gets set up to go against the read only database?

Actually there is one, at least for rails 7 and higher. I traced the error message I was getting to this line here on rails repo
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ea757ae7023fd0f89b6c086831a6f34c80f61f1c/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L202
I could monkey patch the method preventing_writes? on my  development.rb file but I was hoping for a more elegant and maybe table restricted solution

No, I don't think I am using a replica since I am able to write correctly to the database under POST requests or other "writable by convention request methods"

prevent_writes gets set to true if you are using a replica or you set it in a connection -- please add your database.yml to the question

@debugger or if you are using the "reading" connection role at the time. e.g. ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) { #current_preventing_writes would be true inside this block }

@engineersmnky - exactly my point -- this isn't an out-of-the-box rails issue -- this is something that has been set up in this app.

@dbugger just added the details for my config/database.yml file I do have save several replicas set up but I am not connecting to any of them when using the profiler.
Moreover can you think of config syntax I could set on any initializer in order to set hardcoded value to true for current_preventing_writes?

Given the fact you didn't realize you had replicas, you might want confirm you are not using them -- because all available evidence points to the fact you are trying to write to a readonly replica.
